# Undefined Index error with SELECT element, yet it is formatted identically to other select elements in the form

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with an undefined index error message in PHP. I have a form with several `<select>` inputs, and all of them work except for one. On one I get the undefined index error message. I don't understand why this is happening, as it is formatted exactly the same as the other `<select>` inputs. I've made sure that the $_POST assignment in the attached script is referencing the correct element name, and that the option values are correct in the HTML.

The code for the entire form is here: https://pastebin.com/52xtECCT

Here is the code for the `<select>` element:

```
        <td>Team to Represent:</td>
        <td><select name="txtTeamType" id="txtTeamType">
        <?php
            $resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT intTypeofTeamID, strTypeofTeam FROM TTypeofTeams");
            while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $intTypeofTeamID = $rows['intTypeofTeamID'];
                $strTypeofTeam = $rows['strTypeofTeam'];
                echo "<option value='$intTypeofTeamID'>$strTypeofTeam</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And here is the code for the variable assignment. This is the code that throws the error: `$intTypeofTeamID = $_POST["txtTeamType"];`

Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: use `print_r($rows);` for each while loop to see what is returning

Comment: The code you say is causing the error is not in the code block you've posted. Include the bad code __in the question__

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Changing `$intTypeofTeamID = $_POST["txtTeamType"];` to

`if (isset($_POST["txtTeamType"])) { $intTypeofTeamID = $_POST["txtTeamType"]; }`
fixed the issue.